# Netty Stream URL / InputStream

Tags: java, streaming, netty

I'm trying to expand on the functionality here:

https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/3/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/http/file

By providing support to stream URLs instead of Files as the content I'd like to serve is in the classpath within my JAR. Unfortunately I can't seem to figure out a good way to stream a URL or InputStream with Jetty, nor can I find any examples.

Examples or reference to JavaDoc would be appreciated to help get me on the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use ChunkedWriteHandler and write an ChunkedStream that wraps the InputStream.

This should work out quite all..

Comment: It works for me as long as I close the channel. If I try to comply with KeepAlive the client (a browser actually) receive the chunks but then the connection hold and the client wait forever. Simply start from HttpStaticFileServerHandler.java in example/http/file and change the ChunkedFile to a ChunkedStream to reproduce. Any clue?

Comment: Sorry don't get it... can you write a test that reproduce it ?

Comment: I simply edited the HTTP file server in io.netty.example.http.file (form 4.0.0.CR1) to write a ChunkedStream instead of a ChunkedFile and not setting the Content-Size header. Now the browser receive the data and then waits forever. Here is the modified HttpStaticFileServerHandler.java: https://gist.github.com/eskatos/5311587 I expected it to work as is but it seems I'm missing something.

Comment: I updated the gist with the diff against 4.0.0.CR1 so you can quickly see the small change that cause the issue.

Comment: I finished by asking a separate question for clarity purpose: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829810/changing-netty-4-http-file-server-example-to-use-chunkedstream-instead-of-chunke